# write id3 tags using id3.net tagging library C#

Tags: c#, mp3, id3, id3-tag

I am using id3.net tagging library for reading and modifying tags,although with the help of this api i can read all id3 tags but i am facing problem in modifying tags.http://id3.codeplex.com/

```
Id3.Mp3File fs = new Id3.Mp3File(@"test.mp3",Id3.Mp3Permissions.ReadWrite);
Id3.Id3Tag[] tags=  fs.GetAllTags();
tags[0].Album.Value = "test";
fs.WriteTag(tags[0],Id3.WriteConflictAction.Replace);
fs.Dispose();
```

please guide me if i am doing something wrong .if use this overload

```
fs.WriteTag(tags[0],Id3.WriteConflictAction.Replace);
```

it says method or operation not implemented

if i use second overload ie

```
fs.WriteTag(tags[0]tags[0].MajorVersion,tags[0].MinorVersion,Id3.WriteConflictAction.Replace);
```

it says object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

please guide me in this prespective